# Is it true that QuickTime on Windows cannot Trim, but QuickTime on OS X can?

Tags: windows, macos, quicktime

In QuickTime on OS X, I can see a Trim function on the menu bar:

```
Edit -> Trim
```

This can let a user select the begin and end of the video and "Save As" a new one, but on Windows I don't find anything similar.  Is the Windows version of QuickTime missing this?

It is weird that using Windows or OS X, if I search Google for QuickTime, I will find Apple's page for downloading QuickTime 7.6.9, but on my Mac's QuickTime, when I click "About QuickTime", it says it is QuickTime 10.0?  Why do I have version 10 when Apple's website is letting people install 7.6.9?

Comment: QuickTime 7.6.9 is for Windows or Mac OS X <= Leopard. QuickTime 10.0 is for Mac OS X Snow Leopard and Lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the trim feature was added in QuickTime X (10.0; only on Mac OS X Snow Leopard and Mac OS X Lion). The current Windows version of QuickTime is 7.6.9 and doesn't have this feature.

Answer (score 1):

If you want editing features like Trim you need to buy QuickTime Pro for windows. The same was true on the Mac prior to QuickTime X. Unfortunately on the Mac there is no QuickTimeX pro so the ONLY editing feature you get is Trim. When it is installed on the Mac the older version gets moved into the Utilities folder and can be used from there. QuickTime Pro has a lot of features (although sometimes hard to discover) but you can (or maybe I should say could), cut, copy, paste video snippets. Add multiple sound tracks, adjust sound track volumes, trim, throw in additional video overlay tracks etc. Very recently though I've started noticing extreme problems with QT Pro on Windows and most of the editing features are no longer working properly. (Oh yeah QT Pro also supports exporting to a variety of pre-defined and customizable formats).